# Application Insights and Asp.Net core Configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights

I keep reading about the importance of configuring `ApplicationInsights` to reduce unwanted traffic and other things.

How do I do that in an Asp.Net Core application?  There doesn't seem to be an `applicationinsights.config` XML file anymore.

I can see a `ConnectService.json` file in the `Application Insights` folder, but there isn't much in it?

How do I configure AI for an Asp.Net Core application?

Anyone have links to docs?  I can't seem to find any...

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of this is now in code, and mostly documented on the [application insights asp.net core github wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki).

for example, see https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Dependency-Tracking-and-Performance-Counter-Collection where it has

> #### Disabling Telemetry Module Services
>
> In order to disable the services,
>   you need to manually remove the modules from the existing list of
>   services in the method ConfigureServices. Please note that telemetry
>   modules should be removed only after adding Application Insights to
>   the services.

```
 // Removing dependency tracking telemetry module - to disable default dependency tracking 
 var dependencyTrackingService = services.FirstOrDefault<ServiceDescriptor>(t => t.ImplementationType  == typeof(DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule)); 
 if (dependencyTrackingService!= null) 
 { 
     services.Remove(dependencyTrackingService); 
 }

 // Removing performance collector module - to disable default performance counter collection 
 var performanceCounterService = services.FirstOrDefault<ServiceDescriptor>(t => t.ImplementationType> == typeof(PerformanceCollectorModule)); 
 if (performanceCounterService != null) 
 {
     services.Remove(performanceCounterService); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I figured since everything else had moved to a configuration file based approach, including Asp.Net (not Core) I thought this has to be too.  Guess not.  When I couldn't find anything, I just thought it was me.